# Linux web front-end best practices

Tags: integration, system

I want to build a web based front-end to manage/administer my Linux box. E.g. I want to be able to add users, manage the file system and all those sorts of things. Think of it as a cPanel clone but more for system admin rather that web admin.

I was thinking about creating a service that runs on my box and that performs all the system levels tasks. This way I can have a clear separation between my web based front-end and the actual logic. The server pages can than make calls to my specialized server or queue tasks that way. However, I'm not sure if this would be the best way to go about this.

I guess another important question would be, how I would deal with security when building something like this?

*PS: This just as a pet project and learning experience so I'm not interested in existing solutions that do a similar thing.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the specialized service daemon running as a distinct user -- let's call it 'managerd'. Set up your /etc/sudoers file so that 'managerd' can execute the various commands you want it to be able to run, as root, without a password.

Have the web server drop "trigger" files containing the commands to run in a directory that is mode '770' with a group that only the web server user and 'managerd' are members of. Make sure that 'managerd' verifies that the files have the correct ownership before executing the command.

Make sure that the web interface side is locked down -- run it over HTTPS only, require authentication, and if all possible, put in IP-specific ACLs, so that you can only access it from known locations, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems like a very sensible solution to the 'root' issue.

Couple of suggestions:

1. Binding the 'specialised service' to localhost as well would help to guarantee that requests can't be made externally.
2. Checking request call functions that perform the actions and not directly give the service full unrestricted access. So calling a function "addToGroup(user,group)" instead of a generic "performAction(command)".